# Apache Tomcat/9.0.10 while i am trying Compile Error :Files Could not Find Class or Main class

Tags: java, apache

Steps to reproduce:

- [Apache Tomcat/9.0.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQjzW.jpg)
- [Set path to the Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn1CD.jpg)
- [Directory like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fui2U.jpg)
- [Created File Sample Calculator.java and
  Save it on C:\WS-Sample\src\org\calc\wssample\SimpleCalculator.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaZcD.jpg)
- [Compile SimpleCalculator .java in C:\WS-Sample\Classes\org\calc\wssample\SimpleCalculator.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5bad.jpg)
- [Created File Calculator.java as Interface to the SimpleCalculator.java
  saved it on C:\WS-Sample\src\org\calc\wssample\ws\Calculator.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WymiY.jpg)
- [Compiled Calculator.java file on
  C:\WS-Sample\Classes\org\calc\wssample\ws\Calculator.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyxzd.jpg)
- [Generate WSDL  file for service  by redirecting to classes directory and using follow Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89plS.jpg)

After that I got this type error:

```
Error: could not find or load main class org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL
```

Please Help me to Solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Axis libraries, you have to add them to either your webapp or the tomcat lib.

- Download: http://cxf.apache.org/download.html
- Directions for use: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html